# C# automapper format datetime to iso string

Tags: c#, automapper

When Automapper converts a DateTime *that is cast to an object* to a string, it uses the ToString() method which returns a string in a format defined by the culture. How do I configure it so that it always maps to ISO string?

```
        var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "test", new DateTime(2016, 7, 6, 9, 33, 0) }
        };

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, string>().ConvertUsing(dt => dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"));
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        Assert.AreEqual("2016-07-06T07:33:00Z", mapper.Map<string>(data["test"]));
        Assert.AreEqual("2016-07-06T07:33:00Z", mapper.Map<IDictionary<string, string>>(data)["test"]);
```

The first assertion is fine, but the second fails:

```
Result Message: 
Expected string length 20 but was 17. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "2016-07-06T07:33:00Z"
  But was:  "6-7-2016 09:33:00"
  -----------^
```

Comment: If you want to do this for _all_ DateTimes, all you need to do is create a [TypeConverter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters). If you want to do it for specific values, use the `ForMember` syntax on those properties.

Comment: @stuartd What I tried was this: 
            Mapper.CreateMap<DateTime, string>().ConvertUsing(x => x.ToString("u"));

however, that never seems to be called

Comment: That looks like it would work. Can you set up a failing test case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do this:

**Example models:**

```
class A
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string DateTime { get; set; } 
}
```

**Code snippet:**

```
static void Main()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(
        cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<A, B>();
                cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, string>().ConvertUsing(dt => dt.ToString("u"));
            });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var a = new A();

    Console.WriteLine(a.DateTime); // will print DateTime.ToString
    Console.WriteLine(mapper.Map<B>(a).DateTime); // will print DateTime in ISO string
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Code Snippet #2:**

```
static void Main()
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, DateTime> // here is main problem
    {
        { "test", new DateTime(2016, 7, 6, 9, 33, 0) }
    };

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, string>().ConvertUsing(dt => dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"));
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    Console.WriteLine(mapper.Map<string>(data["test"]));
    Console.WriteLine(mapper.Map<IDictionary<string, string>>(data)["test"]);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Your example works fine indeed, and I've discovered that the problem was a bit more elaborate. Please see the updated post.

Comment: I added snippet #2. The problem in your code is that your dictionary `<string, object>, not the `<string,Datetime>`. I believe that in case with collection mappings it uses the declared type of collection, but not the actual one. As you can see, if you'll change from `object` to `DateTime` in your dictionary - it will work.

Comment: The problem is, it is `Dictionary<string,object>` for a reason - it can contain DateTimes, but also strings, numbers or anything else. If there is no other way to do this, I guess we'll have some reengineering to do...

Comment: @BartvandenBurg reengineering should be the way to go. it shouldn't use object when there is generic type.